# Time based VBA script for exercises

Tags: excel, time, loops, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with two columns, one with a list of exercises (33 of them) and a number of reps for each. What I really want is a program that picks a random exercise, displays it with it's number of reps, and has a button that says something like "Done?" When you click it, I want a timer that counts down 20 minutes, picks a new exercise and waits until you click done, and repeat.

I know this isn't hard, but I am no programmer by any means. If anyone has a tutorial or another way of doing this (flash?), I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,
Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is not too difficult but not that easy to explain if you are not used to using userforms etc.

Instead, I have come up with a more simplified solution that may suit your needs. For the purpose of this solution, I am assuming all your exercises are listed in column A and reps in column B. The following code will randomly select an exercise, highlight the chosen selection, and then in column C show a countdown from 20 mins to 0 at 1 minute intervals. As a visualisation:

```
        A              B            C
1       Bench press    20 reps  
2       Abs            10 reps      
3       Lateral raise  15 reps      14 mins <-display of minutes remaining
4       Bicep curl     8 reps
5       Calf raise     10 reps
6       etc
```

To achieve this, first add the following code into a module (**Alt + F11**, then **Insert > Module**)

```
Sub StartExercise()
'Get number of exercises
Dim NumberOfExercises As Integer
NumberOfExercises = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1

'Reset font to normal black and clear anything in column C
Range("A1:B" & NumberOfExercises + 1).Font.Bold = False
Range("A" & NumberOfExercises + 1 & ":" & "B" & NumberOfExercises + 1).Font.ColorIndex = 1
Range("C1:C" & NumberOfExercises + 1).Clear

'Select a random exercise
Dim RandomExercise As Integer
RandomExercise = Int(Rnd() * (NumberOfExercises - 1 + 1) + 1)

'Highlight selected exercise and reps
Range("A" & RandomExercise + 1 & ":" & "B" & RandomExercise + 1).Font.Bold = True
Range("A" & RandomExercise + 1 & ":" & "B" & RandomExercise + 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3

'Countdown from 20 minutes to 0
SetCountDown RandomExercise

End Sub

Sub SetCountDown(TargetCellRow As Integer)

Dim MinsRemaining As Integer
Dim iMins As Integer
MinsRemaining = 20

For iMins = MinsRemaining To 0 Step -1
    Range("C" & TargetCellRow + 1).Value = iMins & " mins"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
Next iMins

End Sub
```

Finally, on your spreadsheet you will need a way of starting the code.

Select **View > Toolbers > Forms** and then from the menu click `Button` and draw it anywhere on your spreadsheet. In the **Assign Macro** dialog box you should see 'StartExercise' as an option. Select this option and click ok.

Now when you click your button you should see an exercise and number of reps become highlighted in bold, red font and '20 mins' appear next to it. This will then countdown to 0 mins. If you then click the button you can start all over again with a random exercise.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this rocks! it makes me want to exercise more! :)

Comment: Good news - glad it worked out and you can get busy in the gym! One more thing, if the solution works out for you then it would be seen as courtesy on this site to accept the answer by clicking the 'tick' mark. This way, other helpers can see that the solution has been accepted and no further help is required